# Flash Actionscript 3.0 Object Position Comparison

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, position

As you may have seen from my previous posts, I am creating a side-scrolling action game in Flash/Actionscript 3.0.

Right now I am trying to get enemy objects to face the player's direction. Here is what I mean (`dartD1` is an instance of the enemy character object. If its `scaleX` is 1, it's facing right; if its `scaleX` is -1, it's facing left):

```
    if (dartD1.x < player.x) {
        dartD1.scaleX = 1;
    } else if (dartD1.x > player.x) {
        dartD1.scaleX = -1;
    }
```

The problem is that the enemies do not change to face the Player during gameplay. Their direction is set based upon their positions relative to the Player at program startup.

I know why this problem is occurring; I have a `scrollScreen()` function that puts the Player object at the centre of the screen. Since the game screen is 700 * 700, the Player is always at position (350, 350) relative to the stage.  Here is my `scrollScreen()` function:

```
        // This function scrolls the MovieClip Containers on the screen
    private function scrollScreen(event:Event):void {

        // Here we offset the elements' 'x' and 'y' coordinates by 
        // the distance between the Player and the centre of the stage
            // Environment Container
            envContainer.x += (stage.stageWidth * 0.5) - player.x;
            // Background Container
                // In all levels but Level 3 (which is in a room, not a landscape) 
                // the background moves more slowly along the 'x' axis to simulate distance
            if (onLevel != 3 && onLevel != 5) {
                bgContainer.x += ((stage.stageWidth * 0.5) - player.x) * 1/20;
            } else if (onLevel == 3) {
                bgContainer.x += ((stage.stageWidth * 0.5) - player.x);
            } else if (onLevel == 5) {
                bgContainer.x += ((stage.stageWidth * 0.5) - player.x);
            }

            //playerDartContainer.x += (stage.stageWidth * 0.5) - player.x;

            // Position the Player at the centre of the game screen ('x' axis)
            player.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.5;

        // Here we offset the elements' 'y' coordinates
            // Environment Container
            envContainer.y += (stage.stageHeight * 0.5) - player.y;
            // Background Container
            bgContainer.y += (stage.stageHeight * 0.5) - player.y;

            //playerDartContainer.y += (stage.stageHeight * 0.5) - player.y;

            // Position the Player at the centre of the game screen ('y' axis)
            player.y = stage.stageHeight * 0.5;
   } // End of 'scrollScreen()' function
```

My question is how do I get the position comparison to work between `dartD1` (enemy) and the Player? To do this I obviously need to get the Player's position relative to `dartD1`. I have tried doing this:

```
        if (dartD1.x < player.localToGlobal(new Point()).x) {
        dartD1.scaleX = 1;
    } else if (dartD1.x > player.localToGlobal(new Point()).x) {
        dartD1.scaleX = -1;
    }
```

This does not work because `player.localToGlobal(new Point()).x` still returns 350, as does `player.globalToLocal(new Point()).x`.

I have looked for solutions on the Internet but have not gotten anything helpful. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me if I don't understand, but....if your player is always in the middle of the screen, can't you just check that the enemies are on either side of him/her on the Stage?

As such, your code...

```
if (dartD1.x < player.x) {
    dartD1.scaleX = 1;
} else if (dartD1.x > player.x) {
    dartD1.scaleX = -1;
}
```

...should actually work. You just need to call it as part of your Event handler, which I assume is running on a frame event or a timer.

It's not the most robust solution, but it'll work.

Edit:

Try this.

```
var pt:Point = dartD1.localToGlobal(new Point(dartD1.x, dartD1.y));

if (pt.x < player.x) {
    dartD1.scaleX = 1;
} else if (pt.x > player.x) {
    dartD1.scaleX = -1;
}
```

Comment: Hi @lunchmeat317, When I print out the player's 'x' position, it's always equal to 350 - the center of the stage. I would have loved to have my original code work - robust or not.

I am calling this code through a Frame Event. I use an EventHandler that then calls the code I have above. I have just tried putting the code within the Handler, and that doesn't fix the problem. Somehow the coordinate comparison is happening only once - at program startup. I think this because I did see one enemy facing the other direction, but that was because it was initialized to the Player's right.

Comment: @ChristianBasar Is that enemy moving at all? (Or, a better question - are you updating the x/y of that enemy instance?) Further...is it a child of the stage, or a child of some other object?

Comment: At present, the enemies do not move at all; their (x,y) coordinates do not change. They are children of a MovieClip Container named `dartDenizenContainer`. `dartDenizenContainer` is then added to `envContainer`, which is then added to the stage, or the `this`.

In the code I've posted, I try to change the direction of only one enemy. But in the past I have tried going through the whole `dartDenizenContainer`, referencing and changing the direction of every single enemy object within. That did not work, either.

Comment: @ChristianBasar See edit. You likely need to convert from local coordinate space to global, and check from there. It looks as though you tried something like that before, but I'm not sure it was entirely right.

Comment: I tried creating the points as you suggest, but I only get two errors:

`Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type.flash.geom:Point` and

`Incorrect number of arguments. Expected no more than 1.`

Comment: I see my mistake; check my edit. `localToGlobal` takes an object of type Point as an argument, not two numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm still having problems. I have tried many different methods of checking the player's position relative to `dartD1.` When I use this check to see if the Player is to the left of `dartD1`, `dartD1` turns as it should: `ddPoint.x > 0`
But when the Player returns to the right of `dartD1` (at which point `ddPoint` should be less than 0), there is no change. After running some `trace()` commands, I found out that when the Player gets to the left of `dartD1`, the value of `ddPoint` shoots up to the 600's! So then when the Player goes back to the right...

Comment: ...the value of `ddPoint` does not turn negative again soon enough. So once the Player reaches the left of `dartD1`, `dartD1` turns left but essentially stays there. I am confused as to the sudden jump in the value of `ddPoint`. It will be at `-8.9, -4.0, 0.0, 5.9, 600.7` for example. And then when I turn the player around, the values go `600.7, 598.1, 587.7`, etc.; they stay well above 0 even though the Player is clearly to the right of `dartD1`.

Answer (score 0):

You should track objects' in-world X and Y separately from their screen X and Y. That way you can deal easily with objects off-screen, and your interaction between objects will be more robust.

The `screenX` of an object would be its `worldX` minus the screen's `scrollX` (and the same for Y's). Thus if the camera is scrolled to (50,50) and the object is at (110,120), its on-screen position would be (60,70).

Once your game is doing that, any comparisons between world positions should work regardless of objects' positions on (or off) screen.

Comment: That tip makes sense.  However, I am having problems getting the player's `worldX`.  I have tried using `localToGlobal` on both the Player and the enemies, but I only get the errors: 

`Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type.flash.geom:Point` and

`Incorrect number of arguments. Expected no more than 1.`

Comment: I would expect you would have to make/implement worldX and worldY (or worldPoint) definitions yourself - the stage only knows its own scale, not a global/world scale. Also: The implicit coercion error sounds like you're trying to assign an x or y value (both of which are Numbers) as a point, which is a problem because a point has both x and y values in it.